Using VBA or formula to Concat if values are the same in concurring cells (countif)
I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this situation.
I have an excel spreadsheet I need to find duplicate numbers in column C and then concat the data in column AB in each of the cells in in AD.
Example:

packs in different font are duplicates. So I'd like them to show page 1002, 4, 1 in each concurring cell for the duplicate packs. The others would be left alone so it would look like this

I was messing around with some a countifs formula but not sure the best way to integrate the concat
=COUNTIF(C:C,C2) = COUNTIFS(C:C,C2,AB:AB,AB2)
The other thing I was messing with (I realize my names are a bit messed up) was to do this in VBA
Set PackRange = Proofsheet.Range("AD1:AD" & lr)
Set PageRange = Proofsheet.Range("AB1:AB" & lr)
Set FillRange = Proofsheet.Range("C1:C" & lr)

    For d = 2 To lr
        PackRange(d, 1) = PageRange(d, 1) & "," & _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(FillRange.Range("AD1:AD" & d), PageRange(d, 1))
    Next d 

but I cannot figure out how to make it Identify each cell in AB for the duplicates.
I'd prefer VBA over a formula but I'll use either as a learning opportunity.
Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Does your version of Excel support FILTER and TEXTJOIN?

You may check this. However, I have used since the dawn of times this one (I have modified it along the way though)

@BigBen yes I have used both FILTER and TEXTJOIN

Try using this =IF(COUNTIF(C2:C6,C2:C6)>1,"Also on Page "&TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(AB2:AB6,C2:C6=C2)),"")

Thanks that was the push I needed! Appreciate your help!

Side note, the VBA equivalent using WorksheetFunction.Filter will fail on the comparison C2:C6=C2. You can use Worksheet.Evaluate, passing it the formula as a String, as a workaround.

@BigBen Sir, correct, that will create a problem, updated with proper answer

Try using the following formula which uses LAMBDA() helper function MAP():


• Formula used in cell AD2
=LET(
     _Pack, C2:C6,
     _StartPage, AB2:AB6,
     MAP(_Pack, COUNTIF(_Pack,_Pack), LAMBDA(α,δ,
     IF(δ>1, "Also on page "&TEXTJOIN(", ",1,
     FILTER(_StartPage,_Pack=α,"")),""))))




Using Dict object to collect page list for each pack

Microsoft documentation:

Dictionary object

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, lr As Long
    Dim Proofsheet As Worksheet
    Dim DupRange As Range, aDup, aPage, aPack
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set Proofsheet = ActiveSheet  ' modify as needed
    ' get last row
    lr = Proofsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set DupRange = Proofsheet.Range("AD2:AD" & lr)
    aDup = DupRange.Value
    aPage = Proofsheet.Range("AB2:AB" & lr).Value
    aPack = Proofsheet.Range("C2:C" & lr).Value
    ' get page list for each pack
    For i = LBound(aPack) To UBound(aPack)
        sKey = aPack(i, 1)
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "," & aPage(i, 1)
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = aPage(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    ' populate output
    For i = LBound(aPack) To UBound(aPack)
        sKey = aPack(i, 1)
        If InStr(objDic(sKey), ",") > 0 Then
            aDup(i, 1) = "Also on page " & objDic(sKey)
        End If
    Next i
    ' write ouput o sheet
    DupRange.Value = aDup
End Sub


